# List Item Permission to Group

Tags: permissions

I have a site group `Group A` in my SharePoint site. And the list of users in the group are `User 1, User 2 and User 3`.

I give read access to `Group A` for a list item. Later I go and add `User 4` to `Group A`.

Whether `User 4` will have permission to that specific list item. It seems to work for list but not for list item.

Please Help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have broken permission inheritance and added item level permissions, then the group assigned to it will have access over the item even if you add new users to that group.

Access is assigned to the group and not directly to user. Hence system will always check for that group.

In your case `User 1`, `User 2`, `User 3` and `User 4` will be able to access that items.